# Improving Cocos2D Spawn System?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, artificial-intelligence

Currently in my game I have my spawn system work like this:

```
[self schedule:@selector(spawnSystem) interval:2.5-(score/30)];
```

Which makes the enemies spawn slower when the score is lower and spawn faster when the score is higher however this is not good and inconsistent because sometimes there are not enough enemies at times etc...

Anyway, is there any way to make it so that I can use CCTime with this spawning method so that there is more enemies at the beginning and after like two minutes there are not as many enemies. Can someone show me an example just so I can be lead in the right direction?

So the bottom line is I want the spawnSystem method to be called one a second in the beginning of the game and after around 2 minutes, it will be called only one every 3 seconds or around there.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are using a linear function y = 2.5-(score/30), This is a decreasing linear function. What you want is more like a quadratic function, i.e y = -x^2 -24x + 10. 
You can try second order, third order polynomials for this purpose.

If you use second order polynomial then your code would be something like

```
[self schedule:@selector(spawnSystem) interval:2.5-score*score-24*score + 10)];
```

[image: Your Function]

> Your Function

[image: quadratic function]

> Quadratic Function

Comment: I see, so I need to use a quadratic function like you stated above. However I have not work that much with math in Obj-C, how would that look in code? I'm sure its pretty simple but I am just a bit confused :P

Comment: Hmm I tried your code sample but it seems that my spawnSystem method only gets called once, something must be wrong!